# Powerpoint 365 proofing languages -> is it possible to check 2 languages simulataneously?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, language

My company's powerpoint presentations usually have to contain text in 2 different languages (slowenian and english). Powerpoint only allows 1 proofing language and so no matter which language is selected, words in the other language will be underlined red as incorrect. This is annoying and while there is a simple fix (turning off spelling correction completely) it is unacceptable for the majority of our users since spelling mistakes happen frequently.

Is there a way to combine proofing languages or dictionaries to allow writing and spelling correction in both languages simultaneously?

Example (say I want to write the word "company"):
Proofing language is set to english: Powerpoint does not underline the word "company" but it would underline the word "podjetje" (slowenian for company). Same applies vice-versa.
I want it to **not** underline both words BUT still underline if a word is misspelled (e.g. kompany)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mdjo Harrymc is correct that you can install multiple proofing languages. To use this feature, you'd have to choose each text shape and mark it as the correct language, English or Slowenian. PPT would then use the correct dictionary for the text.

To do this, select the text or text box, go to the REVIEW tab, click LANGUAGE, then SET PROOFING LANGUAGE. Choose the correct language for that block of text.

Tedious. If I were doing this, I'd create a few "template" slides in whatever layouts I needed, set the languages for each text block, then copy the slides and edit to add new text for each new slide.

There are also two add-ins I know of that will set the language for an entire presentation. With either of them, you could, for example, start with an English language presentation and ignore the spelling errors in Slowenian text, then set the presentation to Slowenian to check the spelling there.

Personally, even though I wrote one of these add-ins, I'd go with Harrymc's suggestion, with the modifications I suggested here.

Comment: Tedious is the correct word for it. We use (on average) around 50 slides per presentation so this is sadly out of the question as it would take several hours. I am surprised that this is not a default feature of Powerpoint; there have to be millions of multilingual users out there and manually setting the language for each block of text cannot be a preferred way of doing things, no?

Comment: I agree. I think PPT's developers designed it for presentations that are all in one language or another, or that have small amounts of text in languages other than the default.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint allows multiple proofing languages.

You may add languages in *File > Options > Language* under
"Office authoring languages and proofing".
Use the button "Add a Language...".

To set some text to a given language, select it.
At the bottom-left of the page you will see the language it's set to:

[image]

Click on the displayed language to launch the Language dialog:

[image]

In the dialog, click a language and then OK. This will change the proofing
language of the selected text.